# Finding a method exists in rest service or not in Java

Tags: java, rest

Hi i am new to Rest Service in Java. First i want to explain my problem and then at the end i will be asking question. 
I am using Mozilla rest CLIENT. My rest class looks like:

```
@Path("/api1")
public class RestService {
    @POST
    @Path("/v1")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String v1(String json){
     //Some code here
} 

   @POST
    @Path("/v2")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String v2(String json){
     //Some code here
}
```

}

Now in this code i have two functions. 
To access v1, call will be:

```
http://localhost:8080/project_name/package/api1/v1
```

To access v2 call will be:

```
http://localhost:8080/project_name/package/api1/v2
```

**Question:**
Now in my rest service class i want to add a patch of code which detects that whether any function which has been called either v1,v2 or v3 exists in this service or not?

Can i do this? Or anyother way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: you'll get a 404 if your trying to hit a hit a rest method that doesnt exist, or have I missed the point of the question?

Comment: You are right but i want to handle this case and send a message back to user that the method you have requested is not available. Can i handle this case?

Comment: You could also add a method that will list all available methods.

Comment: But how that method will be accessed? I just want that user hit rest service and if that method is not available then i should send back a message. I dont want user to first hit a method which w.ill show all available methods and then hit any available method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could add a wildcard response:

```
@POST
@Path("/{what}")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public String v2(String json, @PathParameter("what") String what){
   return "The path "+what+" does not exist.";
}
```

However, since the *user* will never see the direct responses, you can answer with a customized 404:

```
@POST
@Path("/{what}")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response v2(String json, @PathParameter("what") String what){
   return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("The path "+what+" does not exist.");
}
```

This way you can also detect on the client side when something is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for this. It got working. Just i had to change PathParameter to PathParam. I am very thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach for you is to add a fallback response. That will be called when somebody tries to access any non existing WS method.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"*"})
    public String getFallback()
    {
        return "This is a fallback response!";
    }
```

Comment: I have to add this code where? Inside the rest service class?

Comment: Yes, it will be another method in your rest service class which will cater to all requests to non existing paths. I am referring to org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping. Let me try find the @Path value also

Comment: @Maas The Original Poster asks for JAX-RS, not for Spring.